about a compilation error due empty space in foreach list
Background
I want to condense some TikZ commands with \foreach loop, but I encountered some errors.  To fix this, I learnt from an answer for a past question.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \pointA/\pointB in {{(1,0)}/{(2,2)},{(3,4)}/{(2,1)}}{
  \draw \pointA -- \pointB;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Question
Why I can put a whitespace at the start of the list (after {) but NOT before the end of the list (before })?
In other words, why
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \pointA/\pointB in { {(1,0)}/{(2,2)},{(3,4)}/{(2,1)}}{
  \draw \pointA -- \pointB;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

works but NOT
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \pointA/\pointB in {{(1,0)}/{(2,2)},{(3,4)}/{(2,1)} }{
  \draw \pointA -- \pointB;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Context
I hope to make this LaTeX code smarter by avoiding the {} list of coordinates overflowing the right boundary of the window of my text editor.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \pointA/\pointB in {
  {(1,0)}/{(2,2)},
  {(3,4)}/{(2,1)}}{
  \draw \pointA -- \pointB;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I wonder if the arrangement in the above codeblock is a nice way to arrange entries when there're a lot of loop varaibles and list entries.

-- is only allowed to be followed by a node, a coordinate, a pic  or a (possible relative) coordinate specification which starts with either a + or a (. The faulty entry will insert {(2,1)}␣ and that is simply not allowed. (A space after a comma or at the start of the list will be ignored by PGFFor but even then, it wouldn't pose a problem.)

Note that TikZ uses its own parser which differs from standard LaTeX in a number of ways.

See: Q723558, #1354. That's just how PGFFor works. Your last code segment looks good and is a valid input.

@Qrrbrbirlbel thx 4 ref, closing as dupe.  also thx john 4 cmt
